# Image with nested content and borderRadius

Tags: react-native, jsx

I have a problem with `borderRadius` on an `Image` componenent with a nested content. I don't understand why the `borderRadius: 15` doesn't display anything.
If I delete the nested `<Text>` line, the border radius works fine.

```
return (
 <View style={[styles.imageContainer, styles.margins]}>
   <Image source={IMAGES.loginBackground} style={styles.image}>
     <Text>Itinéraire</Text>
   </Image>
 </View>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "#f0f",
    height: 170,
  },
  image: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    position:'absolute',
    left:0,
    right:0,
    top:0,
    bottom:0,
    padding: 10,
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
  },
}
```

Am I doing somthing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it worked fine here. The only difference is I'm using `source={require('imgpath/img.png')}` and didn't set `View` style as an array, since there's no code for `styles.margins`. Are you setting any style somewhere else, like for this `styles.margins`?

Also I noticed you are missing a `)` in the end of your styleSheetCreate:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "#f0f",
    height: 170,
  },
  image: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    position:'absolute',
    left:0,
    right:0,
    top:0,
    bottom:0,
    padding: 10,
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
  },
}
```

It should looks like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imageContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "#f0f",
    height: 170,
  },
  image: {
    borderRadius: 15,
    position:'absolute',
    left:0,
    right:0,
    top:0,
    bottom:0,
    padding: 10,
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
  },
});
```

And I also suggest to add your `const styles` outside your `render()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will try this, thanks. I probably forgot to past some code like style.margins but it doesn't change anything. Obiously, the steelsheet is outside the render, this is also a mistake in the message formating

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<View>` for make transparent border on your Image, for example:

```
<View style={{borderRadius:10}}>
    <Image  borderRadius={10} ....   />
</View>
```